# why is rxjs code doubled in bundle analyzer

Tags: rxjs6, webpack-bundle-analyzer

This is probably more a webpack question than an RXJS question - but something in my code base is including RXJS in different ways. Any tips on how I can tell what has included RXJS?

[image]

Comment: did you ever find out why internal was doubled?